# What is a UNiversal IT Test (UNITT) and how do I prepare for one?

Tags: php, testing

I will be taking an advanced PHP UNiversal IT Test (UNITT) for a position I am applying for.

However, I am unfamiliar with the term 'unitt test'.

What is a unitt test and how would a company execute one?

If anyone is familiar with this, please let me know the best way to prepare

Comment: For what i use the term 'unit test', is a test performed on a unit instead of a whole program. For example, running a test on a single function to test it's functionality without having to execute the whole program.

Comment: Ahhhhhh. Ok, that makes sense.  So my test will probably consist of many code chunks that I will need to explain or perhaps fix if broken?

Comment: You will probably be asked to test some parts of a bigger program with some test modules. Hard to say.

Comment: On closer examination it actually says UNITT - this appears to be a company..?  Perhaps they administer the test.

Comment: note: @Willow is talking about "unitt-test" with double "t" at the end not about unit-test

Comment: maybe the company did a typo, because even a google search for "PHP Unitt" doesn't really find anything that might fit. And for the 10+ years I'm in the PHP community, I have never heard of it either.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the company is getting you to take the online tests administered by Fourth Valley Concierge (see [here](http://unitt.topcareer.jp/info/about_unitt.html)), specifically selecting PHP for the programming language component. You would need to speak to the company in question to see whether this is the only component you will be taking, or if they are requiring you to do the full UNITT test.
As for the test itself, the only information I have located indicates it is composed of a series of multiple-choice questions, and (for the programming component) practical programming skill questions performed through an online testing structure. From their 2012 tests:

> Round 1: an examination of logical thinking, technical knowledge and business knowledge. The subject of technical knowledge includes questions from four categories: algorithms, database, security, and network. The test time is 60 minutes, and the examination includes multi-choice questions.
>
> Round 2: an examination measuring your programming skills. You may choose one programming language among Java, PHP and C++. The examination consists of knowledge-based multi-choice questions and practical programming skill questions. The test time is 35 minutes.

As for preparation, a basic knowledge and familiarity with PHP (since this is apparently the language required for this company), as well as a firm grasp of the basic skills (covering the four main test categories of algorithms, database, security and network) would probably be useful, particularly how to implement standard algorithms, access and manipulate databases, maintain security and interface with the network in the given language. You might also want to speak to the company who is asking you to take the test - explaining that while you are familiar with PHP (which I hope you are given this is what they are testing you for), that you are not familiar with the specific test they have indicated and ask them whether they have more information on it they could give you.

Comment: "Give" may wind up being "sell", for what it's worth.

Comment: I was thinking about asking the company which is trying to hire them for information, rather than the one which may be doing the testing, though I see your point. (I'd be more concerned what other information they might start charging me for later when I'm actually working for them though, if that was the case. "I need the client specs." "Sure, that'll be $20.")